# Why assignment operators of parent class are not accessible from derived class objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

Example:

```
class C
{
  public:
    void operator =(int i) {}
};

class SubC : public C
{
};
```

The following gives compilation error:

```
SubC subC;
subC = 0;
```

"no match for 'operator=' in 'subC = 0'"

Some sources state that it is because assignment operators are not inherited. But isn't it simply because default constructed copy-assignment of `SubC` overshadows them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The copy assignment operator is automatically generated in the derived class.  This causes the base class's assignment operator to be hidden due to the regular name hiding rules of C++.  You can unhide the name in the base class through the "using" directive.  For example:

```
class C
{
  public:
    void operator =(int i) {}
};

class SubC : public C
{
  public:
    using C::operator=;
};
```

Comment: Or call it directly `subC.C::operator =(0);`

Answer (score 2):

A copy assignment operator for a base class does not have the signature required for a copy assignment operator for a derived class. It is inherited by the derived class, but does not constitute a copy assignment operator in it. So even though assignment operators are inherited, just like other member functions, it does not provide copy assignment.

Comment: That isn't true in general.  For example, operator+ can be inherited.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it, but according to [The Man Himself](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#inheriting) (Stroustrup) it's a feature of C++11 to do it with constructors, but it's been in since C++98 to do it with other methods.

This is DIRECTLY lifted from the link:

> People sometimes are confused about the fact that ordinary scope rules
>   apply to class members. In particular, a member of a base class is not
>   in the same scope as a member of a derived class:
>
> ```
> struct B {
>     void f(double);
> };
>
> struct D : B {
>     void f(int);
> };
>
> B b;   b.f(4.5);  // fine
> D d;   d.f(4.5);  // surprise: calls f(int) with argument 4
> ```
>
> In C++98, we can "lift" a set of overloaded functions from a base
>   class into a derived class:
>
> ```
> struct B {
>     void f(double);
> };
>
> struct D : B {
>     using B::f;     // bring all f()s from B into scope
>     void f(int);    // add a new f()
> };
>
> B b;   b.f(4.5);  // fine
> D d;   d.f(4.5);  // fine: calls D::f(double) which is B::f(double)
> ```

So there ya go.  You can probably "take it if you want it" even before C++11, though I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Except copy-assignment operator, other overloaded operator can be inherited.

I agree the opinion that default constructed copy-assignment of SubC overshadows overloaded assignment operator of C.

If SubC don't provide a copy-assignment operator, Compiler would synthese a copy-assignment operation,
as follow:

```
class SubC : public C
{ 
public:
    SubC & operator=( const SubC & other );
}
```

then the 'SubC & operator=( const SubC & other )' overshadows assignment operator of C, 
results in compile error.

If

```
SubC other;
SubC subC;

subC = other;
```

then, this case, compile ok.